# Where is the REQUIRE file situated in Julia?

Tags: julia

I was looking for REQUIRE file using mate in shell command but couldn't find it.
It's related to Pkg..

```
shell> mate ~/.julia/
compiled/     clones/        prefs/         registries/
environments/ conda/         logs/          packages/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using Julia 0.7+.
Which means there is no `REQUIRE` files anywhere.

You may be looking for the `Project.toml` for the global (or other shared) environment.
You will find that (and it's matching `Manifest.toml`) in each subdirectory within the `environments` directory

See the [Julia Docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/toml-files/) for further reading on this topic.